# Printing Text on Thermal Printer using Bluetooth and ESC/POS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm trying to print texts on my bluetooth thermal printer, using ESC/POS commands, but I could not achieve it. I have a class that connects to bluetooth:

```
try
            {
                BluetoothDevice printer = null;

                if (devices == null)
                    devices = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.BondedDevices;

                List<BluetoothDevice> devicesBonded = new List<BluetoothDevice>();

                foreach (var device in devices)
                {
                    if (device.Name != name)
                        continue;

                    printer = device;
                    break;
                }

                socket = printer.CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                socket.Connect();

                if (!socket.IsConnected)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

and a class to print, called `Print(byte[] bytesPrint)`:

```
try
            {
                string textPrint = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesPrint);

                bytesPrint = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textPrint);

                var teste = socket.RemoteDevice;

                var outStream = (OutputStreamInvoker) socket.OutputStream;

                await outStream.WriteAsync(bytesPrint, 0, bytesPrint.Length);
                
                socket.Close();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                socket.Close();
            }
```

It's in `byte[]` to some cases, but it's printing correctly (with no ESC/POS commands). But I need to align the text, change font size, font family and print it! However I couldn't find some library or class with ESC/POS commands and the usage of it. I don't want to use `AppendFormat()` because it's too relative depending the size of paper that I will print.

Does anyone know how to do (with examples please)?

Comment: Found the command manual: https://pos-x.com/download/escpos-programming-manual/  Is that helpful?

Comment: it's been a LONG time since I did this, but this byte array should turn on **bold**; `new byte[]{0x1b, 0x45, 0x00}`

Comment: @Russ No, it doesn't have how to change the font size and font family. Please, post some example to clarify.

Comment: @Jason not working. I tried other commands and worked other things, but that three above in my post (text align, font size and font family) I couldn't find. Please, if you can, post some example.

Comment: have you read the manual for YOUR printer?  These things can vary enormously from vendor to vendor and even model to model.  There are also 235 questions tagged "escpos" you can review for ideas.

Comment: do you even know if the printer supports multiple fonts?  And I'm not sure text alignment  even applies - usually you need to take care of that yourself.  This is a receipt printer, they tend to have basic functionality

Comment: @Jason I spent the whole day on it, searching if the printer supports multiple fonts and the other things above. Since some commands you can apply serif or sans-serif,  for example, to a font to print using ESC/POS command, I thank that has some way to pass some font to print, so to answer your questions: No, I don't know if the printer supports because i couldn't find some answer to it.

Comment: @Jason It's for a lot of types of printers, and all of them has ESC/POS support. So even if I put some `new byte {0x1b, 0x45, 0x00}` as you mentioned, they will read and do the action. Thanks for your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [reference](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=2) to send byte arrays to the bluetooth stream. You can't really print without using ESC/P, it's just hidden under layers of SDK abstractions.